# Passing in parameters for super and subclasses?

Tags: java

The values I am supposed to pass in:

- Name and family should be saved for all instruments
- We need to specify whether a strings instrument uses a bow

When I run my code it gives me the error: "constructor Strings in class Strings cannot be applied to given types;"

```
public class InstrumentTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /**
         * Don't Change This Tester Class!
         * 
         * When you are finished, this should run without error.
         */ 
        Wind tuba = new Wind("Tuba", "Brass", false);
        Wind clarinet = new Wind("Clarinet", "Woodwind", true);

        Strings violin = new Strings("Violin", true);
        Strings harp = new Strings("Harp", false);

        System.out.println(tuba);
        System.out.println(clarinet);

        System.out.println(violin);
        System.out.println(harp);
    }
}

public class Instrument
{
    private String name;
    private String family;

    public Instrument(String name, String family)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getFamily()
    {
        return family;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family)
    {
        this.family = family;
    }
}

public class Strings extends Instrument
{
    private boolean useBow;

    public Strings(String name, String family, boolean useBow)
    {
        super(name, family);
        this.useBow = useBow;
    }


    public boolean getUseBow()
    {
        return useBow;
    }

    public void setUseBow(boolean useBow)
    {
        this.useBow = useBow;
    }
}
```

How do I pass in the parameter family if it doesn't take it?

Comment: In the test code the `Strings` constructor takes only two parameters, so why are you defining it with three? I think it's safe to assume that every `Strings` has an implicit `"Strings"` family value.

Comment: "How do I pass in the parameter family if it doesn't take it?" This sounds like as if you are passing in the family but the class doesn't take it. But the truth is, your class is taking an extra family parameter that is not passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Strings violin = new Strings("Violin", true);
> Strings harp = new Strings("Harp", false);
> ```

The violin and harp don't get passed a family name when they're created, so the `Strings` constructor mustn't expect one as an argument.

```
public Strings(String name, boolean useBow)
```

What do you pass to `super()`, then? If all strings belong to the same family then you can hard code the value. Perhaps just "String":

```
public Strings(String name, boolean useBow)
{
    super(name, "String");
    this.useBow = useBow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you define strings as one single constructor

```
public Strings(String name, String family, boolean useBow)
```

but you try to use it as a different parameters:

```
Strings violin = new Strings("Violin", true);
```

either you need to define a second constructor or use the one you created

Answer (score 0):

> How do I pass in the parameter family if it doesn't take it?

This sounds like as if you are passing in the `family` but the class doesn't take it. But the truth is, your class is taking an extra `family` parameter that is not passed.

Given the comments at the start of `main`, my interpretation is that you are supposed to give all `Strings` a family of "Strings". As you can see from the usage in `Main`, only 2 arguments are passed to the constructor, which means the `Strings` constructor is not supposed to accept a `family` parameter.

Therefore, the constructor should be like this:

```
public Strings(String name, boolean useBow)
{
    super(name, "Strings"); // note that I replaced family with "Strings"
    this.useBow = useBow;
}
```